# PHP Laravel installing error: failed opening required

Tags: laravel-5

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/hejiaxing/work/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/hejiaxing/work/blog/artisan

when I run artisan like this:  php artisan serve

Comment: It looks like you might have to install dependedncies using `composer install` first? If you don't have composer, check getcomposer.org

Comment: I am sure I have install my composer, I can get result when input   
  composer, but I have mv     composer.phar to     local/bin/composer, I find composer isn't a dictionary, there are no composer.phar in local/bin/composer

Comment: I have solved it, I have to create a laravel file via composer